# How to validate multiple functions with one IF statement - Javascript, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, if-statement

I want to validate multiple functions, and for each one returning false, do some animations.

Here's the code:

```
                function validarChido(){ 
                    var dedo = $('#dedo_pick');
                    if(dedo.children().size() < 2){  
                        dedo.animate({'background-color' : 'red'},200);
                        dedo.animate({'background-color' : '#EEE'},200);
                        return false;  
                    }  
                    else{return true;}  
                }

                function validarEx(){ 
                    var valEx = $('#rate1');
                    if(valEx.children().size() < 2){  
                        valEx.animate({'background-color' : 'red'},200);
                        valEx.animate({'background-color' : '#EEE'},200);
                        return false;  
                    }  
                    else{return true;}  
                }

$('#form').submit(function(){  
                    if( validarChido() && validarEx() )  
                            {return true }
                        else  
                            {return false; }
                    });
```

When I send the form, I only see the first function doing the color animation, obviously because the form validation IF statement doesn't evaluate the next function because the first resulted in false here `if( validarChido() && validarEx() )`

Is there a way to evaluate all the functions and see the animation in each one and then send the form if everything is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning false or true do something similar to the following:

```
function validarChido() {
                var dedo = $('#dedo_pick');
                if(dedo.children().size() < 2){  
                    dedo.animate({'background-color' : 'red'},200);
                    dedo.animate({'background-color' : '#EEE'},200);
                    return "error";  
                }  
                else{return "";}  
            }

            function validarEx(){ 
                var valEx = $('#rate1');
                if(valEx.children().size() < 2){  
                    valEx.animate({'background-color' : 'red'},200);
                    valEx.animate({'background-color' : '#EEE'},200);
                    return "error";  
                }  
                else{return "";}  
            }

$('#form').submit(function(){  
     var check = validarChido();
     check += validarEx();

                if( check == "" )  
                        {return true }
                    else  
                        {return false; }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be something like this:

```
$('#form').submit(function(){  
    var validarChidoResult = validarChido(),
        validarExResult = validarEx();

    if( validarChidoResult && validarExResult )  
        {return true }
    else  
        {return false; }
});
```

Comment: Thats Works for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = validarChido();
result = validarEx() && result;
return result;
```